# How do I get the user's Browser in a TMS Web Core Website?

Tags: delphi, browser, tms-web-core

I'd like to know what browser (Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc.) the user has on his computer.

It would be nice if I could also see what version of the browser the user has.

How can I check or get the browser name and/or browser version with Delphi?

Comment: Just like in JS/DOM that would be `window.navigator.userAgent`. From there, see [Browser detection using the user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), which has been done decades ago already - you should find tons of "solutions" for that.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks. I'm busy looking it up now.

Comment: @AmigoJack From what I read is that `window.navigator.userAgent` is very slowly being faded away and replaced with `window.navigator.userAgentData.brands` to get the Browser and Browser Version. I've posted an answer that uses `window.navigator.userAgentData.brands` by default and `window.navigator.userAgent` as a fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the browser name and version from `window.navigator.userAgentData.brands`, but this isn't natively implemented in TMS Web Core yet. `window.navigator.userAgentData.brands` also isn't implemented in all the browsers yet.

But here's an answer using `window.navigator.userAgentData.brands` and then `window.navigator.userAgent` as a fallback in case the browser doesn't support the first method:

```
uses Web;

...

function GetBrowser(IncludeVersion: Boolean): String;
var
  UserAgent: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  asm
    const userAgentData = window?.navigator?.userAgentData?.brands;
    if (userAgentData !== undefined) {
      Result = `${userAgentData[0].brand}`;
      if (IncludeVersion === true)
        Result = `${Result} (${userAgentData[0].version})`;
    }
  end;
  if (Result = '') then
  begin // Fallback in case browser doesn't have "userAgentData.brands"
    UserAgent := window.navigator.userAgent;
    Result := 'Unknown Browser';
    if (UserAgent.indexOf('Firefox') <> -1) then Result := 'Mozilla Firefox'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Safari') <> -1) then Result := 'Safari'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Trident') <> -1) then Result := 'Internet Explorer'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Edg') <> -1) then Result := 'Microsoft Edge'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Chrome') <> -1) then Result := 'Google Chrome'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('Vivaldi') <> -1) then Result := 'Vivaldi'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('YaBrowser') <> -1) then Result := 'Yandex Browser'
    else if (UserAgent.indexOf('OPR') <> -1) then Result := 'Opera';

    if (IncludeVersion = true) then
      Result := Result + ' (Unknown Version)';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm clueless why you're not chaining the default into the `else`s - that assignment doesn't need to happen always. `userAgent` will surely not "_fade away_" because there'll always be HTTP clients that can't be known. like crawlers (Googlebot) and tools (wget).